# Reuse the same pickerview for different textfields in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to display the `pickerview` as input for `textfield` in the `tableview`. I am reusing the same cell xib for all the rows in tableview. at indexpath.row == 1 want to change the age, so the input for `textfield` is `pickerview` containing numbers from `18 to 100`. In the next row when click on `textfield` i need to change gender, so the data in picker view should be `male` and `female`. Please help me in achieving this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just feed the picker view different data source then u can reuse it

Comment: Set tag to textfield and according to that display data in pickerview.

Comment: I am setting the tag but how to access that textfield inside the pickerview delegate methods

Comment: in textfield delegate u disable the keyboard from appearing and show the picker (guess u already do this) at the same time then give a int (`1= name`, `2= age`...) or something depends on the textfield (`if textfield == ageTextField`), check that int in the pickerview delegate and set the data depends on that int

Comment: I will just show my code can u pls explain me how to do this. Plucking my hair not getting the logic to acheive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply reload the picker view:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [Yourpickerview reloadAllComponents];
}
```

Comment: simply calling 'reloadAllComponents' doesn't serve the solution.needs to change the datasource as per the req of textFiled input

Comment: Ya I can do that, but I need to set different data when clicked on textfield in different cells. So I need to write the conditions in the pickerview delegate methods. I not getting an idea to write the conditions.

Comment: Don't write in the delegate of pickerView. Declare a instance variable and change the datasource in the textFieldDidBeginEditing accordingly

Comment: This is one way I can do, but I don't want to create the instance unnecessarily

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag of the textfield and in textFieldShouldBeginEditing get the tag and then add

```
pickerVw = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
pickerVw.dataSource = self;
pickerVw.delegate = self;
pickerVw.tag = TAG_PICKER;
// ... ...
[pickerVw reloadAllComponents];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please See the [GitHub link](https://github.com/sadiqshaikh/textFieldTableview) Has demo made for the purpose in swift

Thanks

Comment: Exactly this is what i need to achieve, but I am unable to understand Swift code. If u don't mind can u please provide this in objective c